# MySQL Select: find records with related records of only one type

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty new to MySQL (coming from FileMaker) and struggle with this. I have to create a list from a MySQL database that meets this definition: List all records from table `Children` that do not have any related record in table `Consultations` where the content of field `Category` is different from `first contact`.

So the list should include children without any consultation as well as those who have only `first contact` consultation but nothing else.

My solution seems to work but is very slow even with a small set of sample records. Is there a simpler and/or faster way to do this?

I tried

```
SELECT
   Chi.ID, Chi.Name
FROM
   Children Chi JOIN Consultations Con ON Con.fk_Child = Chi.ID
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Consultations WHERE fk_Child = Chi.ID AND Categorie != 'first contact') 
GROUP BY
   Chi.ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to JOIN the consultations table (and consequently - no need to group the results), you can also omit the `*` in the subquery:

```
SELECT Chi.ID, Chi.Name FROM Children Chi 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM Consultations WHERE fk_Child = Chi.ID AND Categorie != 'first contact')
```

The EXISTS statements are one of the fastest for this kind of operation, if removing the JOIN and the GROUP is not yet fast enough, you will have to look at indexes and data types in those tables - for this particular query - make sure that `Categorie` is an ENUM field if possible, and add an index on `fk_child`.

Comment: That's true of all the other RDBMSs. It's not quite the case with MySQL - at least historically: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: Now that is much simpler indeed, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Strawberry thanks from the remark. As far as I know performance is much better in recent mySQL versions, I will try to find the benchmark and article I read, as I believe EXISTS queries are now faster than LEFT JOINS.

Comment: yeah - my own benchmark appears to support that view - 15.31 sec for IS NULL vs 4.54 sec for NOT EXISTS (Version 5.5.16)  on the linked example above. I don't like this fact, but the fact speaks for itself!